# How to persist database file in project folder?

Tags: django, docker, sqlite

My application gathers data and stores it in an SQLite database (located in `./data/db.sqlite3`) that we want to exchange through our Git repo along with the code. When I dockerize the app, on each machine the data persists, yet not in the project folder itself.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  gcs:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data
        target: /data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Docker file :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /gcs
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin -y --no-install-recommends
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It mounts the 'data' folder in projects folder to a data folder in the container. When I use Docker inspect the source folder corresponds with project database location:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/Users/rleblon/projects/gcsproject/data",
        "Destination": "/data",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
```

Yet somehow the persistent data is kept elsewhere, never `./data/db.sqlite3` itself gets updated on the host machine.

As I understand Docker creates a regular volume elsewhere and shares that between containers, but what's the point of specifying source and target when the source file was already copied into container? How can I get Docker to use the exact sqlite3 file I want, instead of creating a volume elsewhere and persisting a copy there?

Comment: What happens if you try to map db.sqlite3 directly? e.g. in volumes source: "./data/db.sqlite3" with target: "/data/db.sqlite3" ?

Comment: Same issue. App works fine, but data is not persisting in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be both copying your sqlite3 db into your image - via the line in your Dockerfile

`COPY . .`

which given your defined working directory in the Dockerfile

`WORKDIR /gcs`

and the looks of your directory structure, may copy the db to

`/gcs/data`

as well as mounting the same sqlite3 db via your docker-compose file in line

```
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./data
        target: /data
```

to

`/data`

in your running container of this image.

So you may have two versions of your data running in a container of this image: at

`/gcs/data` <-- copied over to the image in Dockerfile

`/data` <-- mounted as volume in docker-compose

Make sure you are not copying a version of the db into the image via your Dockerfile.

If your `gcs` service interacts with the version of your sqlite3 db located in `/gcs/data`, and not the mounted volume at `/data`, then any changes to the db would not persist after the container is destroyed.

On the other hand, if your app is pointing to the mounted volume version of your db at `/data`, then make sure the permissions set on your host / image allow for the db operations you desire.

Remember you are using a bind mount in your compose file - this means the mounted directory is shared between your host and the running container.  This statement

`As far as I understand Docker simply creates a regular volume elsewhere on my computer and shares that between containers`

is true of docker volumes, but not the `bind` mount type you have used.  See e.g., the [offical docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) or [this nice summary post](https://dev.to/darkmavis1980/how-to-persist-data-with-docker-compose-ik8) for a nice breakdown of the difference between volume types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful! The problem was the location of the folder in the container, `docker-compose.yml` should have contained the parent folder (target /gcs/data instead of just /data).

I should have looked in the parent folders within the container. My fault was that I somehow assumed, when looking at docker inspect info, that the information there was based on the WORKDIR (gcs) folder I specified in the Dockerfile, but apparently it's based on the root folder which makes sense.